# 'Safely Remove' mounts the Seagate Backup plus drive again and again

Tags: mount, external-hdd, 15.04

I had upgraded my ubuntu to 15.04 recently and while using my Seagate external hard disk, I found there is no Unmount option but a new Safely Remove option is provided. And it is not working properly as it keeps mounting the drive a few seconds later again after I had clicked the Safely Remove.

I found a few answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381108/safely-remove-using-command-line/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540425/safely-remove-on-external-portable-drive-keeps-remounting-drive) but those are command line oriented.

I'd like to know if it is a bug or some other issue with my system. And whether the Unmount option can be included again.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085