# mount partition on ubuntu startup in similar way when clicks on partiton

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

I want to mount `/dev/sda8`  partition on startup.
 For that I created a folder in /mnt/mount_folder. And edited the  `/etc/fstab file`   with following entry 
 `/dev/sda8 /mnt/mount_folder ext3 defaults 0 0`  
when i run command  `sudo mount /dev/sda8 -v` 
It runs fine ie all the content of partition is coming in that folder. mount and umount both works fine
But the issue is the partition is not coming in the list of  `Devices that comes on file manager's left side`.

 .
Please explain how to mount a partition in a similar manner when we click the partition when clicks from the devices!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/517738/289138 - if it answers your question then use the arrows beside it to increase the points ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to see it in your file manager. Then you have to mount it to

```
"/media/<user_name>/<some_directory>".
```

Or

```
"/media/<some_directory>"
```

for all users.
In your case add to fstab

```
/dev/sda8 /media/mount_folder ext3 defaults 0 0
```

You can also do it manually, same way as it is done by nautilus.

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER/mount_dir
sudo mount /dev/sda8/ /media/$USER/mount_dir
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,  Ubuntu does not have a permanent directory in there for any partition, when clicks the partition on the fly it is creating folder. how to do that. can u plz tel

Comment: I do not understand the question. If you want to mount "on the fly", then click it. If you want to mount automatically and permanently, then create a directory and update fstab.

Comment: I want to mount in the same way Ubuntu does, how to do that? This is my question, hoping it is clear to u.

Comment: What is "in the same way"? Mounting to /media is quite a same way.

Comment: when clicks on partition ubuntu creates the folder name with same as  partition label and when unmount delete that folder, with your approach there will be a permanent folder which i don't want

Comment: I see. You can do it with a bash script. But what is the goal? Why not just use nautilus, which already has this script? If you give a good reason, I can help to make scripts.

Comment: goal is to learn new things and avoid using tools, m doing this, as my eclipse refers android sdk in that partition and every time I have to manually mount the partition, when i boot the system, so want to get rid of that