# How to show mounted partition in devices list

Tags: 14.04

How to show the mounted disk in devices list, my disk is mounted on /media

Here is the screen shot.[image]

Comment: why not edit /etc/fstab... make sure you use UUID instead of /dev/sda sdb if you have multiple hdds.

Comment: where should I put UUID, can you please put the exact entry

Comment: Which mounted partitions doesn't show there? Could you give us the output of mounted partitions? Use `lsblk` or `df` (friendler thand `findmnt`, `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts`)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make folder in /media ex. /media/Data then you can mount it to folder you've created before by using command :

```
# mount /dev/sda /media/Data
```

Now your mounted disk should appear in device list.

Comment: Maybe you mean `/media/$USER/...`, where `$USER` is your username? BTW, there are [better ways to mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342188/how-to-auto-mount-from-command-line)