# How to unmount MTP USB device from command line

Tags: usb, unmount

I have both the Bus and Device numbers for a USB device I want to unmount.
I tried resetting the USB device like so 
[How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)

but it doesn't unmount it from the desktop.

Comment: Since MTP devices are just another type of mounted devices this question is possible a duplicate of [How to auto-mount from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342188/how-to-auto-mount-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

MTP devices are mounted via *gvfs (gnome virtual filesystem)*.
You'll need to use the propper tools for managing *gvfs*, like `gvfs-mount` or `fusermount`.

- First use `lsusb` to get your mtp *device number* and *bus number*. I think you already have this.

  Simple example using *lsusb+grep* for a Nexus 4:

  ```
  $ lsusb | grep Google 
  Bus 002 Device 025: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc.
  ```
- Then use `gvfs-mount`:

  ```
  gvfs-mount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A{busnumber}%2C{deviceNumber}%5D
  ```

  Replace *busNumber* and *deviceNumber*, also remove the brackets.

  You should end with something like:

  ```
  gvfs-mount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C025%5D
  ```
- If `gvfs-mount` doesn't work, try with `fusermount`:

  ```
  fusermount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C025%5D
  ```

Hope it helps.

UPDATE: Sorry,`gvfs-mount` and `fusermount` seems to be designed to work without sudo as they are intended to manage fuse-based mounts by non admin users.

UPDATE 2: I observed the correct path is : `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`, while testing by myself on Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 , using *1000* instead of *yourUsername*.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try either option I get sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 999, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: Sorry ,try `fusermount -u /run/user/myUser/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C025%5D`, fusermount seems to work without root permissions for mounts using fuse. Answer edited...

Comment: Updated answer, you should check if it solves your question.

Comment: [gvfs is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/a/342209/349837) in favor to `gio mount`.

Answer (score 1):

I was asking the wrong question.

Instead of  figuring out how to unmount the device, I needed to find out what process or daemon was claiming it.

I issued

```
ps aux | grep mtp
```

which gave me a few mtp related processes and compared with the camera mounted and unmounted to get the specific process

and then

```
pkill -9 gvfsd-mtp
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df
```

to find all mounted devices, and you get more information if you run the following command

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

or even better in a **wide** terminal window (if necessary)

```
sudo lsblk -fm
```

When you have identified the USB device, you can unmount it with the following command line

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, for example '/dev/sdb1'

-o-

This is **unmount**. The buffers are flushed, so it is safe to unplug the device. The device has still power on, so it can be 'seen on the desktop', and it can be mounted again. This is different from **eject**. An ejected pendrive will be powered off, and must be unplugged and plugged in again if you want to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

You can unmount by using below commands, First check list of all the blocks and mount paths. `lsblk`

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```