# Mount partition at startup the same way the file manager does it - NOT with /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, login

I want to mount a partition after login the same way the file manager does it when I click an unmounted device under 'Devices'. Ideally, I want to use the same underlying daemon the file manager uses.

It should NOT be mounted via fstab. Basically, the result should be as if I opened the file manager after login and clicked on the device, without the need to elevate rights, unmountable by the user, same access rights, same place in the file hierarchy (`/media/user/partitionlabel-or-UUID`).

After login - so different devices could be mounted for different users, for example.

How could this be done? A search drowns relevant information in the gazillion answers via `/etc/fstab`. The one suggested answer for mounting a samba fs at login doesn't help here.

Comment: You can use `gio mount` (formerly `gvfs-mount`) - see for example [How to auto-mount from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/342209/178692)

Comment: but all of those options can be done with /etc/fstab and then you just show the volumes in the file manager???? It sounds like you basically just want them to show up in file manager? or is there something about /etc/fstab you are trying to avoid? ....same with gnome-disks

Comment: Found the solution by scrolling down in @steeldriver's reference. `gio` is no good because I use Kubuntu, but `udisksctl` is the correct way to do it. Now I need to test it a little more.

Comment: think its named solid-hardware5, it uses udisks as backend so the end result will probably be the same.

Comment: or the dbus interface `busctl tree org.freedesktop.UDisks2`

Comment: @WU-TANG: See my answer below. This accounts for mounts at each user's `/media/<user>` tree, mimics the file manager's behavior, is tolerant of already mounted or unmounted disks, and can be changed on-the-fly by the user themselves without having to resort to root privilege. Solution is useful especially for remote logins to systems with removable media. `fstab` was designed at a time where removable media were not common. This is more in line with modern usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is really easy if you know what to look for. A DE-agnostic way to automount disks at login is to use `udisksctl`. It is often used to mount loop devices, but it can also mount drives. The necessary `polkit` rules are already present since `udisks2` is used under the hood for the automount mechanisms of the file managers. Therefore, it can be run without elevated access rights.

`udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdn1` or `udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/<disklabel>` mounts the disk from the command line under `/media/<username>/<diskname or UUID>`.

The line `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdn1 2>/dev/null` added to the user's `~/.profile`, which is run after each graphical, non-graphical or remote login, attempts to mount the disk and fails silently if already mounted so the user is not irritated by an error line.

For completeness, `~/.bash_logout` with a `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdn1` could unmount this disk at logout if desired.

For a broader solution, put this in `~/.profile`:

```bsh
# mount disk with specified label if unmounted and present
userdisks=( "disklabel 1" "disklabel 2" "disklabel 3" )
for disk in "${userdisks[@]}"
do
    if ! lsblk -l | grep -q $disk ; then
        udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/$disk
    fi
done
```

and add this to `~/.bash_logout`:

```bsh
# unmounts disks at last logout of user
count=$(who | grep -c $(whoami))
if [ $count -eq 1 ] ; then
    userdisks=( "disklabel 1" "disklabel 2" "disklabel 3" )
    for disk in "${userdisks[@]}"
    do
        if lsblk -l | grep -q $disk ; then
           udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/$disk
        fi
    done
fi
```

You have to put all the labels of devices you want to mount in the space-separated `userdisks` array. Make sure that a label with spaces is surrounded by quotation marks.

This lets the user know that the disk is mounted on the command line, silently skips mounting when disk is already mounted and gives an error when disks are missing.

Only when the last user session gets logged out, the disks are unmounted.

This setup has been a convenient timesaver when logging in via `ssh` to a laptop with removable devices, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Overall the answer above is correct, however here is my tip.
For me solution with `lsblk -l | grep -q $disk` didn't work out because for some reasons my disk still was in the output.

I fixed the issue by changing that line to

```
lsblk -l -o MOUNTPOINT | grep <expected_mount_path>
```