# Create shortcut from command

Tags: command-line

How can I achieve the following:

type `vdm` in the terminal 
and that will be replaced by `wine Program Files/The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1/bin`

I also wanted `vdm` to work in any folder I am whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a text file `~/.bash_aliases` and put

```
alias vdm='wine "Program Files/The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1/bin"'
```

in it. You'll need to restart your shell for it to take effect.

The `.bash_aliases` file is safer and easier to edit than editing the `.bashrc` file directly. It's automatically loaded by `.bashrc` on 11.04 and later.

See also [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)

Comment: That's a good point. `~/.bash_aliases` is a better place for Aliases.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way is via an [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html). They look as simple as this:

```
alias vdm='wine "C:\Program Files\The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1\bin"'
```

After you plumb that in, you can run `vdm` (as long as it's from a bash shell) and your Wine command will run. You may need to play around with the syntax of the Wine statement a little.

For that to persist, you'll need to save it to one of your bash configurqation files. My original post suggested just adding that line to `~/.bashrc` but as [root54 points out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74746/shorcut-from-command/74749#74749), you should probably use `~/.bash_aliases` if you're on a relatively new install. If it doesn't exist, don't worry, just create a new file and stick that line in.

After you make changes to either of those files, you need to run  `source .` to reload bash's config.

---

Alternatively you can create a bash function, again in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function vdm {
    wine "C:\Program Files\The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1\bin"
}
```

Again, after putting this in, you'll want to run `source .`

---

And finally, if you need something more meaty (you don't for this simple command) you can write a full script and stick it in `~/bin`.

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
touch ~/bin/vdm
chmod +x ~/bin/vdm
nano vdm
```

And copy in something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wine "C:\Program Files\The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1\bin"
```

The advantage of bin scripts over anything else is they're slightly more portable. You don't have to hack apart or replace your `.bashrc` if you want to take them to another computer. But they're a bit more fuss to create.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal type `alias vdm='wine Program Files/The VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.3.1/bin`

If you reboot, though, it will most likely be unset, so you will have to put the line inside the `~/.bashrc` file.

so `gedit ~/.bashrc` and at the bottom, paste the alias-line in the file.