# How do you change/edit reboot command to "rebooot" (Edit pre-existing terminal commands)

Tags: command-line

Where does the terminal command (reboot) live? If I wanted to change it to "rebooot" or "rbt" what would I need to do?

*Without creating a separate bash script for a completely separate command.*

Comment: Read http://askubuntu.com/questions/74746/create-shortcut-from-command and http://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias

Answer (score 2):

You can find where most executables are using "which":

```
~$ which reboot

/sbin/reboot
```

You can make an alias using "alias":

```
~$ alias rbt="reboot"
```

Comment: I tried running this

which showdesktop

and it didnt return anything

Answer (score 1):

Reboot is an init script in /etc/init.d and the binary is in /sbin.  You can create a custom bash command and name it rbt to do the same thing as reboot.

```
echo "rbt(){ reboot }" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: If you use alias, you'll also want to put that into your bash_profile, otherwise it will not be available next time you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work in all shells, create a link (it's **system wide and shell independant**):

```
ln -s $(which reboot) /bin/rbt
```

This creates a link from where the executable `reboot` lays to `/bin/rbt`. When typing `rbt` in a shell `reboot` is executed instead.