# How to add an alias to a command in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bashrc, alias

By typing a manually specified command in terminal I want to execute some other command.

How could add an alias to a command? Can i do that with the help of the terminal or should I edit some kind of file?

Comment: See also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
alias new_name='old command'
```

To create a permanent alias you have to edit the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

More info [here](http://dotfiles.org/.bashrc)

More .bashrc files [here](http://dotfiles.org/.bashrc)

Comment: There is no manual entry for alias. It is a built-in command. You must look at the man page for the shell.

Comment: Changed it. ty.

Answer (score 17):

On the bash command line it is simply a case of typing:

```
alias my_command="Command to run"
```

For example to create a short command run a long listing you could do:

```
alias ll="ls -l"
```

The quotes are not required if you are not adding switches to the aliased command.

Answer (score 8):

To make permanent changes you can put your aliases separetely in `~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: Don't forget to run `source ~/.bash_aliases` for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the `alias` built-in command in the shell you're using, or you can write a script which does what you want. Assuming you are using bash as the shell (which is the default), you can type `man bash` and skip down to the `ALIASES` section, for documentation on aliases in bash.

Answer (score 1):

I write a GUI for adding/editing alias commands. You can also use it from commandline like this:

```
addalias -add "sinstall" "sudo apt-get install"
```

https://github.com/isamert/addalias

Comment: I hate this and it shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To learn about aliasing: visit http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html

To make the changes permanent (i.e. to be read everytime you start a shell) add the alias commands you typed in the terminal to the file ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: This has been flagged for deletion.  Can I suggest you add the relevant bits of the link into the answer to make it self contained?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a file in your home for collecting all the aliases `.bash_profile` by writing `nano ~.bash_profile` and simply write on the file the commands/shortcuts you want to create, for example:

```
alias edbp='nano ~/.bash_profile'
```

and then validate it sourcing the file, so running

```
source ~.bash_profile
```

Remember that every time you modify your document you have to run again `source ~.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

#### Aliases' File

Add aliases to the file `~/.bash_aliases` and create it if it doesn't exist. For example, I have:

```
$ more ~/.bash_aliases
alias trop='tree --dirsfirst -L 1'
(...)
```

#### Alias Help

```
$ alias --help
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    Define or display aliases.
    
    Without arguments, `alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
    form `alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output.
    
    Otherwise, an alias is defined for each NAME whose VALUE is given.
    A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
    alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
    
    Options:
      -p    print all defined aliases in a reusable format
    
    Exit Status:
    alias returns true unless a NAME is supplied for which no alias has been
    defined.
```