# Change command name in terminal

Tags: rename, installed-programs, sublime-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an alias to a command in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal)

I use the sublime text 2 text editor for developing in Ubuntu. When I want to open a file form the command line, I need to type `sublime-text-2 <file-name>`.

I would like to be able to tab after `sub` to get that, but there is sublime-text and subl or something that which also auto-complete.

Is there a way to change or create an alias for the name sublime-text-2 and call it 'sub' or just 'sublime' or even something completely different like 'texta'?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Not necessarily a duplicate -- non-alias solutions (as with  @LnxSlck's) are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
sudo ln -s /pathforsublimetext2install/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Also, I recommend that you install sublime text 2 through a PPA, because it will integrate better with Unity/Gnome.

To install this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: That is how i installed it, cheers.

Comment: Manually creating symlinks in `/usr` is not cool. If you must, create them in `~/bin` instead.

Comment: Care to explain why is not cool? As defined /usr/bin contains applications for the system's users. Even more /usr/bin is one of the major subdirectories of the /usr directory. It is the directory in which most standard programs are kept, along with on-line manuals and most libraries (i.e., collections of code that are commonly used by programs).

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can get command completion for aliases in bash on Desktop Ubuntu.

For example, here's my `scanh` alias (which will tab complete) from .bash_aliases:

```
alias scanh='egrep -v "^ \*|^\/\*|^$" '
```

You can create an alias for yourself in the same way. E.g.,

```
alias text2='/pathtofile/sublime-text-2'
```

You can also, if you prefer, move the blocking commands out of the way.

For instance, if a command called `sublet` is confounding your tab-completion, the process might look like this:

```
$ which sublet 
/usr/bin/sublet
$ ls -la sublet
/usr/bin/sublet
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/sublet /usr/bin/xsublet
```

Linking the sublime-text-2 command to something shorter works the same way.  Just make sure that the link you create is in your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$ ln -s  sublime-text-2 /usr/local/bin/sub
```

Any of the above directories, /usr/bin/, /usr/sbin, etc., will work.
If you have a stand-alone script or binary, you can also move it into the path directly:

```
$ sudo mv sublime-text-2 /usr/bin/sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `alias` command. I put such things in my `~/.bash_alises` file, which is called by my `~/.bashrc`. You can also put the following in `.bashrc`, either way it's up to you.

I have lines like this:

```
alias del='gvfs-trash'                          #I habitually avoid rm
alias def='surfraw google define:'
alias st2='sublime-text-2'
```

After changing `~/.bash_aliases` *the first time*, type `source ~/.bash_aliases`. In the future that will be done when you start your computer.

HTH.