# How to create shortcut commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an alias to a command in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal)

I am looking for a way to make a shortcut command. For example, I want to execute the command `g++-4.7 temp.cpp -o temp` by running either `G temp.cpp -o temp` or `g++ temp.cpp -o temp`.

Is there a way to change the application's name for not having to type the complete name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases can be created by supplying name / value pairs as arguments for the alias command. An example of the Bash shell syntax is:

```
$ alias name='unix command with options'
```

For example:

```
$ alias copy="cp"
```

In your case, `alias G="g++-4.7"` should work.

Comment: it seems that it's not working but the name is added when i press TAB, i mean It's what i'm getting : 

The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder (You will have to enable component called 'universe')
Try: apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: but when i press tab instead of just g++-4.7 there's an extra g++.

Comment: @T0MXeOnLuCiFeR `alias G="g++-4.7"`

Comment: tnx it worked...:)