# block certain dangerous commands?

Tags: command-line, sudo

In my  High school there are few computer having Ubuntu 14.04 installed and many students know the **Root**  password,
how  can I block/disable  certain dangerous  commands like :- `rm -rf /` `rm -rf *` `:(){:|:&};:` to avoid Data loss ?

Comment: what about the simplest way? Changing the root password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a terminal command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430702/remove-a-terminal-command)

Comment: @parto that question/answer assumes they do not have the admin password.

Comment: Cannot change root password as many students and teacher use it !!!

Comment: I see no reason why students and faculty should have the root password. Use sudo properly and limit its impact. That said, if you can't do that, educate the students and faculty of the power they wield.

Comment: @Parto Also, none of the solutions [there](http://askubuntu.com/q/430702) achieve any security-related goals such as preventing people from inflicting deliberate harm. For [aliasing](http://askubuntu.com/a/430708/22949), users can redefine their own aliases or execute commands in such a way as to bypass aliases (e.g., with their full path). Users can put back a command that [has been deleted](http://askubuntu.com/a/430704). And users can similarly make their own copy--or, if they cannot do that, *bring in* their own copy--of [a non-setuid command they can't run](http://askubuntu.com/a/430740).

Comment: @Ashu Have you considered using guest sessions that revert on reboot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Impossible. Absolutely impossible. If they know the admin password they can do a-n-y-t-h-i-n-g and can always revert any change you make to the system.

If you are the admin of those system you need to re-install those computers. There is no telling what those students did to those systems (for all you know they installed a keylogger, a mailserver or some dubious script and know your password seconds after you changed it) and create an admin account with a **secure** password.

> Cannot change root password as many students and teacher use it !!!

Yes you can and yes you should. There should be 1 or 2 people that know the admin password. Other people can have elevated access but they still do not need the admin password.

Comment: yes it' not possible to prevent totally that a command may be enabled back, but how to avoid accidental run of dangerous commands? command 'foobar' for example, how to disable "sudo foobar"?