# Is there a way to get a description for each command or app that "apt-get install" can install?

Tags: apt

When we type in `emacs` in Ubuntu's Terminal, it will show a list of apps or commands we can install.  I am not so interested in what it is particularly for `emacs`, but want to find out if there is a way to get a one line or longer description of each of the commands?

Such as

```
<some-command> emacs
```

and it will show

```
emacs24   The GUI version of emacs
jove      A simplified version of emacs (non GUI)
[...]
```

Comment: Very similar: http://askubuntu.com/q/649629/380067