# Unable to install vlc or any software

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, vlc

The image shows the output when I try to install VLC for last 8 hours i have read all stuff on the same problem tried everything

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu first time and also am not a programmer.

there is some issue when I am trying to update my system, which cannot be resolved by existing solutions on askubuntu

The error is

> W: Failed to fetch
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find
> expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
> sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Output I got :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: You should probably try and get a fresh default `sources.list` file and replace your current one with that. See http://askubuntu.com/q/652190/367990

Comment: Please try http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository & update question after you have tried with what you have done. Thank you

Comment: This looks like an intermittent problem, as http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release now definitively contains `universe/binary-amd64/Packages`. If it persists, what do you get, when you download that address? Can you please upload it to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and include a link in your question? In the mean time, I'm going to vote to close this question, because it cannot be reproduced.