# Error updating mailman

Tags: apt, upgrade, mailman

Received this error message today doing `apt-get upgrade`

```
Setting up mailman (1:2.1.16-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Looking for enabled languages (this may take some time) ... done.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/eu  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/eu not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/no  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/no not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/he  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/he not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/tr  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/tr not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/pt_BR  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/pt_BR not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/lt  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/lt not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/sk  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/sk not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/nl  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/nl not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/et  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/et not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/hr  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/hr not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/de  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/de not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/it  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/it not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/zh_CN  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/zh_CN not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/fr  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/fr not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/sr  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/sr not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/zh_TW  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/zh_TW not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ru  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ru not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ja  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ja not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/cs  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/cs not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/fi  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/fi not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/el  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/el not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ca  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ca not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ar  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ar not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/sl  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/sl not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/pt  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/pt not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/hu  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/hu not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/es  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/es not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/vi  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/vi not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ko  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ko not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ro  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ro not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/gl  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/gl not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/fa  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/fa not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/da  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/da not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/pl  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/pl not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ia  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ia not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/uk  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/uk not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/sv  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/sv not empty, not removed.
Removing unmodified files from /etc/mailman/ast  done.
Directory /etc/mailman/ast not empty, not removed.
Installing site language en ............................................ done.
Downgrade detected, from version 0x20112f1 to version 0x20110f0
This is probably not safe.
Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package mailman (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3. My question is:

***What would cause this?***

**Update:**
Per @Ravan's comment below I was able to fix the problem by

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
rm mailman*
apt-get clean all
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Although things are better now, I still don't have an answer to what would have caused this.

Comment: refer [here](https://opensource4me.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/how-to-fix-e-sub-process-usrbindpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/)

Comment: would love an explanation as to what went wrong but thanks, that works

Comment: I had the same issue. I have the mailman.postinst file saved if you are still interested. Your solution worked. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 3):

After you have deleted all the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`, it is difficult to say what the problem was.

Therefore, don't delete something, if you need an explanation for your problem. Or read **[this](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165)**, before you do something.

The error occurred in file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mailman.postinst`, this was the error message for that:

> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 1

And this is the problematic code or the place from which one could look for the error.

```
for lang in ${site_languages}; do
  printf "Installing site language ${lang} " >&2
  mkdir -p ${mm_etc}/${lang}
  for file in $(ls ${mm_dist}/${lang}); do
    printf . >&2
    langfile=${lang}/${file}
    ucf --debconf-ok --three-way ${mm_dist}/${langfile} ${mm_etc}/${langfile} 2>/dev/null
  done
  printf " done.\n" >&2
done
```

More can not be ascertained, unfortunately.