# can we do install everything from repo?

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, disk-usage

can we do `apt-get install *` (install everything the repo has), if so, how many GB it would require?

Answer (score 2):

The installation size depends on the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` but would be [about 680 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror).

---

And no, you can't install all packages via

```
sudo apt-get install *
```

Why? See below,.

But you could with this command, **but you should not do that! Please. Ok?**

Ok?! Can [I trust you](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165)?

Ok.

```
aptitude -F %p search '!~i!~v' | xargs sudo apt-get install
```

---

If you start the command `sudo apt-get install *` in a terminal with `bash` you would see something like this (it depends of the content of your current folder).

```
$ sudo apt-get install *
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package brackets
E: Unable to locate package brackets-shell
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-Bold.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-Bold.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-ExtraBold.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-ExtraBold.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-ExtraLight.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-ExtraLight.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-Light.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-Light.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-Medium.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-Medium.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-Regular.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-Regular.otf'
E: Unable to locate package Dosis-SemiBold.otf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Dosis-SemiBold.otf'
E: Unable to locate package dosis.zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dosis.zip'
E: Unable to locate package makefiletab3
E: Unable to locate package projectlibre_1.6.1-1.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'projectlibre_1.6.1-1.deb'
E: Unable to locate package SIL Open Font License.txt
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'SIL Open Font License.txt'
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb'
```

Compare the error messages with the output of

```
$ ls -lsog
total 74960
    4 drwxrwx---   5     4096 Aug 31 20:09 .
   84 drwxr-xr-x 246    86016 Aug 31 21:54 ..
    4 drwxrwxr-x   8     4096 Aug 30 13:45 brackets
    4 drwxrwxr-x  12     4096 Aug 30 13:57 brackets-shell
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    59588 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-Bold.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    57896 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-ExtraBold.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    57888 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-ExtraLight.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    59028 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-Light.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    58396 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-Medium.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    59944 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-Regular.otf
   60 -rw-rw-r--   1    58524 Jul  5  2013 Dosis-SemiBold.otf
  256 -rw-rw-r--   1   261233 Aug 31 20:09 dosis.zip
    0 -rw-rw----   1        0 Jul 17 17:36 .foo
    0 -rw-rw----   1        0 Jul 17 18:10 .foo.bar
    4 drwxrwxr-x   4     4096 Aug 30 20:09 makefiletab3
12380 -rw-rw-r--   1 12675606 Aug 30 14:31 projectlibre_1.6.1-1.deb
    8 -rw-rw-r--   1     4529 Aug 31 14:09 SIL Open Font License.txt
61792 -rw-rw-r--   1 63270648 Aug 30 17:23 virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
    0 -rw-rw-r--   1        0 Aug  5 21:13 .vminfo
    4 -rw-rw-r--   1      172 Aug  2 19:35 .zip
    0 -rw-rw----   1        0 Jul 17 17:36 .zzyGir
```

All clear? ***;)***

Comment: oooh... Trying to get some nice votes?? XD

Comment: @DevRobot yes =)

Comment: @user68186 better not. the one who knows, knows what to do. All others should not try.

Comment: My answer deleted and size information added to yours!  :P ;-)

Comment: @user68186 done :)