# Editing Folder permissions for var/www/html

Tags: permissions, apache2

I need to edit my php.ini file so I can upload large sql files into MySQL, but I don't know how to do it.

If I go to var/www/html and try and drag-and-drop phpinfo.php there it won't let me (not enough permissions).

Can someone please tell me how to edit the permissions of the folder so I can add files to it? (terminal method is preferred, but UI is fine too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the permissions and [you should not use a command from which you do not know what it does and what impact it has](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165).

Copy the file using the terminal with proper access privileges:

```
sudo cp /path/to/your/phpinfo.php /var/www/html
```

And the following access rights should be enough for `phpinfo.php`

```
sudo chmod 640 /path/to/your/phpinfo.php
```