# Ubuntu corrupted when apt-get install and remove python 3.5.0

Tags: apt, 15.04, python

I'm using freshly installed Ubuntu 15.04 in that I want to install the newer version of Python. So, in terminal I typed this.

```
sudo apt-get install python 3.5.0
```

And it downloaded and installed something. After that when I entered `python3` on terminal it opened the version 3.4.3 and not 3.5.0.

Though it didn't installed the version that I wanted I entered this

```
sudo apt-get remove python 3.5.0
```

When it's done I found out that ***Ubuntu Software Center*** was disappeared and when I restarted the OS, Ubuntu's launcher and menu bar was disappeared but the files on the desktop are visible and  openable. But ctrl + alt + t is not opening terminal.

So, what went wrong here?

Comment: First, you would have had to `sudo apt-get install python3=3.5.0`, because the package name is `python3` and you have to select a version by using the syntax `package=version`, without any space in between. But in the official repository is only `python3` in version `3.4.3-1` available anyway (you can check with `apt-cache policy python3`). That means you would have to add a PPA providing the newer version first anyway.

Comment: Second, Python is an important part of your Ubuntu system. Many commands are indeed just Python scripts! Therefore you must not have removed Python3!

Comment: `apt-get install` didn't throw any error but downloaded and installed something for about 85 MB. I just tried to remove what I installed( remove command makes sense to me).

Comment: Do you still have the terminal output of the `remove` command? If yes, copy it and save it! This might be your chance to restore the other packages!

Comment: No, I'm reinstalling the Ubuntu now. Is this a bug of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I don't want to be offensive, but this was rather a bug in the interface between your computer and your chair... To compare it with your car, we could say that you just told the mechanic to take out the gearshift or any other vital part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `bash` uses spaces to divide the command line into arguments (read `man bash`), you really did:

```
 sudo "apt-get" "remove" "python" "3.5.0"
```

that is, remove two packages "python" and "3.5.0". Many packages (see list below) depend on `python`, and can not work without it. Therefore, if you are removing `python`, you must also remove (See list).

Please read `man apt-get`, and **Understand** commands, especially commands using `sudo`, Before you execute them.

If you don't understand the command, some one else could tell you (in unexplained computer jargon) "Aim at foot. Fire!", and you, not understanding, would do it. Many people do.

Comment: Where did you find the `-s`?

Comment: In the second part of the question, posted as an Answer below. Oops

Comment: Well, the `-s` is a parameter for `apt-get` telling it to just simulate all actions, without actually touching the disk. Because we only want to shoot our feet with blanks! ;)

Comment: I understand `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no- act`, I was showing how things get parsed. And doesn't the `-s` mean `-s, --shell` to `sudo`?

Comment: After reinstalling Ubuntu, still I would like to install Python 3.5.0 I tried tar.gz `make` but `make` test failed. May I upgrade? How do I do it(link)?

Comment: Like I said, read `man bash` and `man apt-get`. These documents, already on your system will explain everything.

Comment: Ask your new question "I would like to install Python 3.5.0. ..." as a New Question

Answer (score 0):

When I start the command `sudo apt-get remove python 3.5.0` on my 15.04 system in a bash (no, not really, I've used `sudo -s apt-get remove python 3.5.0`), that is the result. In other words, you've got your system unusable. 
I say, you're faster if you reinstall and read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165).

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot apt-xapian-index apturl arronax arronax-base arronax-nautilus
  asymptote atom bzr bzr-builddeb calibre calibre-bin cdbs colortest-python
  cython deja-dup deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles deja-dup-backend-gvfs
  deja-dup-backend-s3 diffuse dput dropbox duplicity elyxer gcalcli
  gcj-4.9-jre-lib gconf2 gdebi gdm gedit gedit-latex-plugin gimp gimp-gmic
  gimp-gutenprint gimp-plugin-registry gir1.2-gda-5.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  git-buildpackage gksu gnome-control-center gnome-doc-utils
  gnome-exe-thumbnailer gnome-pkg-tools gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-share gobject-introspection gtk-doc-tools guake
  gufw gvfs-backends gvfs-backends-goa gyp ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table
  ibus-unikey inkscape iotop ipython ipython-qtconsole itstool jobs-admin
  jobservice libappstream-glib-dev libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev
  libatkmm-1.6-dev libatspi2.0-dev libavahi-glib-dev libbonobo2-dev
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-dev libboost-all-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev
  libboost-mpi-python1.55-dev libboost-mpi-python1.55.0 libboost-python-dev
  libboost-python1.55-dev libcairo2-dev libcairomm-1.0-dev
  libcanberra-gtk3-dev libclutter-1.0-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libcogl-dev
  libcogl-pango-dev libcogl-path-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev
  libdbusmenu-glib-dev libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev libdee-dev libenchant-dev
  libgail-dev libgcj-common libgcj15 libgconf2-dev libgda-5.0-4 libgda-5.0-bin
  libgda-5.0-common libgda-5.0-dev libgda-5.0-postgres libgdamm-5.0-13
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgee-0.8-dev libghc-gconf-dev libghc-glib-dev
  libgirepository1.0-dev libgksu2-0 libglade2-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libglibmm-2.4-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgnome-vfs2.0-cil libgnome2-0
  libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnome2-dev libgnome2.24-cil
  libgnomecanvas2-dev libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-dev libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-dev libgnomevfs2-extra
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgtk-3-dev
  libgtk2.0-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev libgtksourceview-3.0-dev
  libgudev-1.0-dev libhighgui-dev libibus-1.0-dev libidl-dev libindicate-dev
  libjson-glib-dev libmagick++-6.q16-dev libmagick++-dev
  libmagickcore-6.q16-dev libmagickwand-6.q16-dev libmagickwand-dev libmx-dev
  libnotify-dev libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-dev libopencv-highgui-dev
  libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-ocl-dev
  libopencv-superres-dev libopencv-videostab-dev liborbit2-dev
  libpackagekit-glib2-dev libpango1.0-dev libpangomm-1.4-dev libpeas-dev
  libpulse-dev libpurple-bin libreoffice-gnome librsvg2-dev libsdl1.2-dev
  libsdl2-dev libsmbclient libsoup2.4-dev libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev
  libspice-client-gtk-2.0-dev libspice-server-dev libunity-dev
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libzeitgeist-2.0-dev lilypond-data lyx lyx-common meld
  mercurial mercurial-common monodevelop morituri mplayer2 nautilus-share
  ndiff node-gyp nodejs-dev npm nut-monitor ocrfeeder oneconf oneconf-common
  openshot pdftk picard pyrenamer python python-appindicator python-apport
  python-apt python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-beautifulsoup python-boto python-bs4 python-bzrlib python-cairo
  python-cddb python-characteristic python-chardet python-cherrypy3
  python-cloudfiles python-colorama python-commandnotfound python-configobj
  python-crypto python-cssselect python-cssutils python-cups python-dateutil
  python-dbus python-debian python-debianbts python-debtagshw python-decorator
  python-defer python-defusedxml python-dev python-dirspec python-discid
  python-distlib python-distro-info python-distutils-extra python-dns
  python-dnspython python-ecdsa python-enchant python-feedparser python-gconf
  python-gdbm python-gflags python-gi python-gi-cairo python-gi-dev
  python-glade2 python-gnome2 python-gnomekeyring python-gobject
  python-gobject-2 python-gobject-2-dev python-googleapi python-gpgme
  python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-gtk2-dev python-gtk2-doc python-gtkspell
  python-gudev python-hachoir-core python-hachoir-metadata
  python-hachoir-parser python-html5lib python-httplib2 python-idna
  python-imaging python-jinja2 python-kaa-base python-kaa-metadata
  python-keybinder python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-ldb python-libxml2
  python-lockfile python-lxml python-mako python-markdown python-markupsafe
  python-mechanize python-mlt python-musicbrainzngs python-mutagen
  python-nautilus python-ndg-httpsclient python-netifaces python-nose
  python-notify python-ntdb python-numpy python-nut python-oauth
  python-oauth2client python-oauthlib python-oneconf python-openssl python-pam
  python-paramiko python-parsedatetime python-pexpect python-pil
  python-pil.imagetk python-pip python-pisa python-piston-mini-client
  python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-pyasn1
  python-pyasn1-modules python-pycurl python-pyexiv2 python-pygments
  python-pygoocanvas python-pyicu python-pyorbit python-pyparsing python-pypdf
  python-pyqt5 python-pyqt5.qtsvg python-pyqt5.qtwebkit python-qt4
  python-renderpm python-reportbug python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel
  python-repoze.lru python-requests python-routes python-samba python-sane
  python-scour python-secretstorage python-serial python-service-identity
  python-setuptools python-simplegeneric python-simplejson python-sip
  python-six python-soappy python-software-properties python-speedtest-cli
  python-sqlite python-support python-talloc python-tdb python-tk
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-tz
  python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntutools python-uritemplate
  python-urllib3 python-usb python-utidylib python-vobject python-vte
  python-wadllib python-webob python-wheel python-wstools python-wxgtk2.8
  python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python-xapian python-xdg python-yaml
  python-zeitgeist python-zmq python-zope.interface python3-oneconf
  python3-smbc r-base-dev rapid-photo-downloader regexxer reportbug rubber
  samba-common-bin samba-libs sessioninstaller smart-notifier software-center
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins soundconverter
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome terminator
  texlive-full texlive-lang-indic texlive-music totem-plugins transmission-gtk
  trash-cli ubuntu-dev-tools ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-system-service update-manager update-notifier
  update-notifier-common valac valac-0.26 valac-0.28 vlc-plugin-samba
  xdiagnose y-ppa-manager yelp-tools youtube-dl youtube-dlg zeitgeist zenmap
  zim
```

Comment: This confuses me, as you should get *"E: Unable to locate package 3.5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '3.5.0'"*...