# Desktop environment without Python dependency

Tags: desktop-environments

I'm looking for a desktop environment without Python dependency unlike Unity and GNOME. Because I don't want to get in to any trouble like this [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/675997/136502).

Comment: You should read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165) **;)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of minimalist desktops that don't depend on python.

One is `blackbox`. If you run `apt-cache show blackbox | grep -i pyth`, you can see there's nowhere for python to be listed.

Another is `openbox`. If you run the same command you can see this:

```
apt-cache show openbox | grep -i pyth                     
Recommends: obconf, python-xdg
Suggests: menu, fonts-dejavu, python, libxml2-dev, tint2, openbox-menu, openbox-gnome-session (= 3.5.2-6), openbox-kde-session (= 3.5.2-6)
```

Python there is recommended but not required.

Same with `xubuntu-desktop`. `apt-cache show xubuntu-desktop | grep -i pyth` shows nothing. Also, `razorqt-desktop`.

You can install any of those desktops with `sudo apt install` or `sudo apt install`  and add desktop name. Use `apt-cache search <name>` to ind the desired desktop in the available repositories

Comment: What about Lubuntu(`LXDE`) and its `lubuntu software center` do they have any dependency of Python?

Comment: Yes it does have dependency on one python package

Comment: Good one, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If you read my (IMHO best) answer to [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/675997/136502), you will see that the user did NOT learn Linux, and thought that `sudo apt-get remove python 3.5.0` would affect Python version 3.5.0. It does not. It `remove`d `python`, and his system stopped working.

Don't be that user! Make heavy use of the `man` command, don't run `sudo anything` until you fully understand what it does.

There is **NO** piece of software that is safe from an uninformed user using `sudo`.