# How can I delete a file in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I've examined some topics but I couldn't delete a file under `/usr/share/applications`

I downloaded Eclipse but somehow I also installed two icons and named them differently.

What I want to do is to delete an icon (not the program) that belongs to Eclipse: there are two different Eclipse icons on my `/usr/share/applications` which are named "Eclipse Mars" and "Eclipse Mars Java". I want to delete one of them and I have tried to delete using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg Eclipse Mars Java
sudo rm -f /usr/share/applications/Eclipse Mars Java
```

However, none of the above have worked...

*Is there any other way to delete one of these icons?*

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-3  ; but check if you really want to delete that file (supposing it exists, which I doubt) --- it's not recoverable.

Comment: Does the name really have spaces? If yes, try `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/"Eclipse Mars Java"`. There is no need to `-f`, and the first command is irrelevant.

Comment: Be VERY careful with rm. You could have ended up deleting  3 files where "Mars" and "Java" would be deleted in the CURRENT directory. Had it been an existing file it would be gone. As a tip: use "ls" to examine if what gets returned it what you want to delete.

Comment: @NoWeDoR and you should read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165) **;)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see two icons because you have two desktop files: either in `/usr/share/applications` and/or in `~/.local/share/applications`. The file name of the desktop file isn't the same in your file manager nor your Launcher. In your file manager and in your Launcher you see what's defined inside the desktop file, note the entry `Name=`

*Example*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse C++
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=/opt/eclipse-cpp/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Eclipse-CPP
```

[image: Eclips icon screen shot]

`grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse C++' ~/.local/share/applications`

```
/home/aboettger/.local/share/applications/opt_eclipse_cpp.desktop
```

---

Therefore find the **right** path and file name with the commands below:

- **<kbd>Eclipse Mars Java</kbd>**

  ```
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- **<kbd>Eclipse Mars</kbd>**

  ```
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars [^J]' /usr/share/applications
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars [^J]' ~/.local/share/applications
  ```

Delete the **right** file via (**NOTE**, that are the same commands as above with the additional command `sudo rm` or `rm`)

- **<kbd>Eclipse Mars Java</kbd>**

  ```
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' ~/.local/share/applications | xargs rm
  ```
- **<kbd>Eclipse Mars</kbd>**

  ```
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars [^J]' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm
  grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars [^J]' ~/.local/share/applications | xargs rm
  ```

Comment: That answers the question , but probably not the best solution.

Comment: When I write grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications it shows me /usr/share/applications/Eclipse Mars Java.desktop and  what should I write exactly now?

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: If this is the file that you no longer need: `grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm` or without the `grep` command: `sudo rm "/usr/share/applications/Eclipse Mars Java.desktop"`. Note the double quotes.

Comment: When I enter grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm it response like rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
When I enter  -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm it shows me -lr: command not found
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
When I enter sudo rm "/usr/share/applications/Eclipse Mars Java.desktop" it shows me rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/share/applications/Eclipse Mars Java.desktop’: No such file or directory

Comment: `grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications | xargs sudo rm it response like rm: missing operand Try 'rm --help' for more information.` means, there is not longer a desktop file with "Name=Eclipse Mars Java"

Comment: Check the output of `grep -lr 'Name=Eclipse Mars Java' /usr/share/applications` again there should be no output.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen better? =)

Comment: Yes, I have finally solved this issue. Thank you so much for all your helps.

Comment: @A.B.purge option with dpkg or apt-get

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the name of the package and how you installed it.

From your question, I am guessing you used `dpkg`

The options for dpkg (and apt-get) are to remove or purge.

remove saves system configuration files, purge does not

> -r, --remove package...|-a|--pending
>                 Remove  an  installed  package.  This  removes everything except
>                 conffiles, which may avoid having to reconfigure the package  if
>                 it  is reinstalled later (conffiles are configuration files that
>                 are listed in the DEBIAN/conffiles  control  file).   If  -a  or
>                 --pending  is given instead of a package name, then all packages
>                 unpacked, but marked to be removed in file /var/lib/dpkg/status,
>                 are removed.
>
> ```
>           Removing of a package consists of the following steps:
>
>           1. Run prerm script
>
>           2. Remove the installed files
>
>           3. Run postrm script
>
>    -P, --purge package...|-a|--pending
>           Purge  an  installed  or  already  removed package. This removes
>           everything, including conffiles.  If -a or  --pending  is  given
>           instead  of  a  package  name,  then  all  packages  unpacked or
>           removed, but marked to be purged in  file  /var/lib/dpkg/status,
>           are purged.
>
>           Note:  some configuration files might be unknown to dpkg because
>           they  are   created   and   handled   separately   through   the
>           configuration  scripts.  In that case, dpkg won't remove them by
>           itself, but the package's postrm  script  (which  is  called  by
>           dpkg),  has  to  take  care  of  their  removal during purge. Of
>           course, this only applies to files in  system  directories,  not
>           configuration   files   written   to   individual   users'  home
>           directories.
>
>           Purging of a package consists of the following steps:
>
>           1. Remove the package, if not already removed. See --remove  for
>           detailed information about how this is done.
>
>           2. Run postrm script.
> ```

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/dpkg.1.html

Neither option removes files from your HOME directory, such as .desktop files. For those you have to manually find and remove them.

Files with spaces in them need quotes or escape the spaces or use tab completion

```
rm "file with spaces"
rm file\ with\ spaces
rm file<tab><tab>
```