# how to add alias as a command in bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc

In my bashrc i want to add an alias which would run a shell script.

I am trying the below :-

```
export termlist=/usr/data/log
export runterm=cd $termlist; bash termlist.sh
```

termlist.sh is the shell present in /usr/data/log directory. I want to just type runterm in the terminal and it should go to this directory and run the shell script. but its giving error as :

```
 bash termlist.sh : command not found
```

Comment: You want to add an alias but you define and export variables.

Comment: how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

How to create an alias is documented [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal).

The proper way to handle your situation is using a wrapper script instead.

Include your commands in a little bash script `~/.local/bin/runterm`, with the contents:

```
termlist=/usr/data/log
cd $termlist
$termlist/termlist.sh
```

Once the script is set executable, you will be able to execute it by simply running `runterm` at the terminal.

Instead of `~/.local/bin`, use `/usr/local/bin` if you want the executable to be available for all users of the system.