# Alias adder script in terminal

Tags: scripts, alias

Recently i was adding some command aliases to .bash_aliases file in user home folder.
I am wondering if there is some script that i can run to add aliases to that file.
What I mean is :
some script that first I can add as command alias and after that for example if I run command lets say

```
addalias
```

it will execute the script.

The script will do the following job:
Go to the end of the text file.
Add line for example :`alias aosunpack='/home/elementalfx/aosfirmware/unpack-aos-kernel-g10'`

Then save the file.
And finally reload the bash_aliases with command `. ~/.bash_aliases`

But to make it even better script will first ask for alias name and then for a command to execute or file to execute.

Thats the thing that I dont know how to do. Can somebody lead me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding aliases is manual labour but can be done with a 1-liner on command line. This will create your alias and add it to bash_aliases and also reload them:

```
echo "alias aosunpack='/home/elementalfx/aosfirmware/unpack-aos-kernel-g10'" >>
~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases
```

All you need to do is adjust it to your commands for any other command you want (if you put those into a text file you can omit the `&& source ~/.bash_aliases` and add `source ~/.bash_aliases` at the end. This will not prevent duplicates but the last one added will be the active one.

Partly taken from a comment by hobs from this question: [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) There are more good answers and comments in that topic.