# Opening a non-utf8 encoded text file

Tags: gedit, character-set

I sometimes need to open text files that are encoded in EUC-KR.

`man gedit` gives:

> ```
>    --encoding
>           Set the character encoding to be  used  for  opening  the  files
>           listed on the command line.
> ```

This can be used to open specific files with the desired encoding:

```
gedit --encoding euc-kr readme.txt
```

However, each file to be opened requires a similar command to be typed.

I can run `iconv` on the file(s), but then I have to deal with different file versions.

Do I have better options for dealing with non-utf8 text files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to specify the encoding when opening the file is to use the Open Files dialog.

On the bottom left, you will see an drop-dwon option for *Character encoding*. If you haven't used the encoding in Gedit before, scroll down to *Add or Remove...*.

In the new dialog, scroll down the list of *Available Encodings* until you find the one you want, then click *Add* to send it to the list of encodings on the right, then *OK*.

That's it. After that you easily open the file with the correct encoding.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I kept looking for it in the File, Edit, Tools, and View menu...

Answer (score 6):

#### Nautilus Action

To have access to custom open options for Gedit from the file browser Nautilus we may define a [Nautilus Action](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus) to have an entry in the right mouse click context menu which opens a selected file in Gedit with certain options. The command line for your action would then be:

```
/usr/bin/gedit --encoding euc-kr %b
```

By doing so you will be able to open files with euc-kr encoding on selecting your custom  context menu entry but still be able to just double click open other files having a standard encoding.

---

#### Custom .desktop file

To be able to select Korean encoding as option in the open with dialog or as standard option we may create a custom `kr-gedit.desktop` file (e.g. located in `~/.local/share/applications`) to include options in the `Exec=` line. Add this custom "application" to the files properties dialog (on right click on a .txt file).

- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

---

#### Alias

For the command line you may define an alias to open files with a Korean encoding. This can also be [made permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias):

```
alias kr-gedit="gedit --encoding euc-kr"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add auto detected charset in file: ~/.gconf/apps/gedit-2/preferences/encodings/%gconf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="auto_detected" mtime="1444988803" type="list" ltype="string">
        <li type="string">
            <stringvalue>UTF-8</stringvalue>
            <stringvalue>WINDOWS-1251</stringvalue>
            <stringvalue>UTF-16</stringvalue>
        </li>
    </entry>
    <entry name="shown_in_menu" mtime="1444988803" type="list" ltype="string">
        <li type="string">
            <stringvalue>WINDOWS-1251</stringvalue>
        </li>
    </entry>
</gconf>
```

Here the line "<stringvalue>***</stringvalue>" - the desired cahrsets

Comment: How does this help the OP?