# Can write arabic and can't read it

Tags: language-support

i have serious problem and i can't solve it my text editor (gedit,KWrite etc) can write Arabic but it can't read it i installed arabic package on my computer and also i configure my layout to arabic so if anyone can help me

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: explain more. what's wrong with it?

Comment: it's apear like this : Ø§Ø³ÙØ§Ù ÙØ­ÙØ¯ ÙØ­Ø¬ÙØš
???????? ??­??? ??­???

Comment: instead of اسلام <-- this is arabic word and when i type it in my text editor like gedit it show normal but when I read anything alse it show like this: Ø§Ø

Comment: See this answer: [gedit - Opening a non-utf8 encoded file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file/282673#282673)

Comment: @userCS I'm glad the linked answer helped you. You may want to upvote the linked answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarifying comment, you seem to have an encoding problem. In gedit, after having selected "File -> Open", you can explicitly select the character encoding that fits the document you want to open. Probably it should be something else but UTF-8 for the files in question.