# Arabic text does not render

Tags: 14.04, fonts, language-support, arabic

I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. Now any Arabic text is displayed as squares, as shown in the image below. I tried installing the Arabic language pack but this did not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you please launch a guest session, and check if you have the same problem there?

Answer (score 0):

1-After installing arabic language you should see in `languages menu` if you not see you should add by check arabic from `install/remove languages`.
2-if still the same after rebooting in `regional formats tab` temporary choose `العربيه` after rebooting change it again to your default language.

> Note : if prompt to update an external feature you should update.

[image: photo]

> edited

i have same problem with subtitle file but it depend on application as you see `gedit` have a problem with the file but on vlc on subtitle tab subtitle language section i edit the the default language to arabic and works fine .[image]   as you see it depends on how application encoding language and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file?lq=1) is away to change gedit encoding .

Comment: thank you for your answer..but the problem is persistent..the problem is, i have a dictionary its interface is in arabic and instead of the characters are displayed in arabic they are just question marks..please help

Comment: take a look sir updated.