# how to make Ubuntu compatible with arabic

Tags: keyboard-layout, compatibility, text, arabic

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu.

Is there some way to make Ubuntu compatible with Arabic language?

I don't mean the keyboard layouts  , I mean when open an exiting windows text file it's like this:

[image: Photo 1]

But when I create, type, save, re-open the text file Arabic works fine:

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file

Comment: Can you two work out a deal where the question is solved or marked as duplicate?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i don't think it's a duplicated , but it's solved

Comment: my stupidness don't know how to mark it as solved :D

Comment: I think you're just `Funning` me. Either you post the answer or whoever / whatever posts an answer then you click the BIG GREEN CHECK MARK next to the answer to mark it as solved. Otherwise your question registers as unanswered for the next 1500 years which makes it embarrassing when aliens land from another planet.

Comment: you are awesome too @WinEunuuchs2Unix :D i will type answer now 
thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the answer at [opening a non utf8-encoded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file)
this is how I fix it

1 - open gedit > press open

2 - open file dialog will appear

3 - press keyboard settings / layouts settings / Encode settings / add-remove bla bla :D

you will see it at right/left bottom

4 - another dialog will appear from  it add the Arabic  windows & ISO

that's it !!

---

P.S : 1 small issue >> every time you want to open Arabic text you will need to open it from open file dialog and select Arabic windows/ISO from the dropdown