# How to add Cyrillic in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: text-processing, language-support, encoding, cyrillic, russian

I have already installed Russian keyboard layout.

In language support -> installed languages I already have Russian.

But when I open text file with Cyrillic I have encoding problems. This files was created in Windows earlier. With new files I don't have this problem.

> Ïðîäâèíóòàÿ ìàìà
>
> Ìàìà ñòðàòåã ñåìåéíûé íàø
> Åùå óñòðîèò íàì øàáàø
> Ìû ñ íåé íå óìðåì îò ñêóêè,
> Çà ýòî öåëóåì åé ðóêè.

UPD. I tried to specify Windows-1251 encoding manually while opening file and Cyrillic has shown correct. I don't have problem in files, which encoding was set as UTF-8.

Comment: Did you tried to specify Windows-1251 encoding manually while opening file with Gedit? Did you try Kate editor?

Comment: @N0rbert I tried and Cyrillic has shown correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a non-utf8 encoded text file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually text files with Russian (Cyrillic) text are created in Windows with Windows-1251 (or CP-1251) encoding. Less often they use ISO 8859-5. While modern systems use UTF-8.

You can always check file encoding with `file` command:

```
$ file utf8.txt 
utf8.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

To open files correctly and automatically you can use feature-rich text editor as `kate`.
Or specify encoding manually when you open file with `gedit` or other editor.

Comment: `file` command may be showing the incorrect format. My files were shown as ISO-8859, although they were Windows-1251. That was the core of the problem, as well. You can use `iconv` command to convert the file formats. `iconv -f Windows-1251 -t UTF-8 file_name` worked in my case.