# bash script isnt working

Tags: scripts, alias

I have written this simple type alias script in my bin directory in home

```sh
#!/bin/sh
alias kp='ls –L'
alias ldir='ls –aF'
alias copy='cp'
```

and saved it in the name myenv. Then I have changed the mode using

```
chmod +x /bin/myenv
```

then execute it using the command

```
myenv
```

but after this when I use kp it says kp command not found. Why?

Comment: This answer is not clear. You should add more info and details to it.

Comment: @Bajiru you commented under *question*. s/answer/question/ maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

Your script runs in a sub-shell by default. (It opens a new shell and runs your script. After the script has finished running, its modified environment is destroyed.)

If you'd like to change your current shell environment settings you have to:

```
source myenv
```

or:

```
. myenv
```

See `man bash` [Shell Builtin Commands / Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc30).

Answer (score 0):

First, because `–` character that you used in `alias kp='ls –L'` and `alias ldir='ls –aF'` is not the same with `-` (you can see that is a little bit longer). Try:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
alias kp='ls -L'
alias ldir='ls -aF'
alias copy='cp'
```

Just copy and paste from above.

Second, if you want that the script to have the expected effect, just put this line in `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /bin/myenv
```

Anyway, the best way to create aliases in Ubuntu is to use this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/5278/147044.

Comment: Thanks.. But creating alias isnt my goal. I am just learning to create shell scripts