# Strange message now appears when I open up my terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql, gnome-terminal

I was recently installing MySQL and everything seemed to go just fine, however, when I opened up my terminal to test a few things out, I got a strange message:

```
No command '“alias' found, did you mean:
 Command '0alias' from package 'zeroinstall-injector' (universe)
“alias: command not found
“alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus”
daniel@Pangolin:~$
```

I have never seen this before and have no idea exactly what it means. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most probably you have a typo on `~/.bashrc` (or some other file read by bash on startup), please provide the contents of `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this error has something to do with the installation of MySQL, but anyway...

Open your `~/.bashrc` file (from terminal with `gedit ~/.bashrc`), search for the following line:

```
“alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus”
```

and replace it with:

```
alias android-disconnect='fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus'
```

This line define an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) (`android-disconnect`) for this command: `fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus`. If you don't intend to use this alias in the future, is better to delete the above line.