# How to open AbiWord (or Writer) in fullscreen via terminal

Tags: command-line, abiword

I`d like to learn how to open Writer or AbiWord in fullscreen via terminal. I mean opening without nesessery to tipe F11 after opening. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

I found that this works.

```
abiword & sleep && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,fullscreen
```

It's quite similar to Radu's suggestion except it deals directly with the window manager. The sleep *might* not be required but in my experience, there's a short delay before Abiword takes focus. If your computer is really slow, you might need to extend the sleep to two or three seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such an option for AbiWord. See [`man abiword`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/abiword.1.html) in this sense. Using only `abiword` command you can start AbiWord maximized with the help of `--geometry` option (argument). For example if your screen resolution is 1366x768, then you can start AbiWord maximized using:

```
abiword --geometry=1366x768
```

Anyway, there could be a trick to start AbiWord in fullscreen mode using [`xdotool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool/). To install it from terminal, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

After is installed, you can start AbiWord in fullscreen as follow:

```
gedit & sleep 2 && xdotool key F11
```

Increase or decrease the time (in seconds) for `sleep` if is necessary. This time should be a little bit bigger that the time it takes to open AbiWord.

Now if you like it, you can add an alias for the above command, let say `abiwordfs`:

```
alias abiwordfs="gedit & sleep 2 && xdotool key F11"
```

See also: [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)