# Create new terminal commands

Tags: command-line, apt

I recently installed eclipse the manual way. Extracting the file, setting up eclipse.desktop etc. It all works flawlessly. I also know it is possible to install eclipsee using `sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform`. If I use this method I can use the command `eclipse` in the terminal, and the program will start.

Now the manual way I used does not enable the `eclipse`-command in the terminal. Instead if I use `eclipse`-command it asks me to install eclipse from the Softwarecenter (`sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform`).

I wondered if there was some way of setting up a command like this to start eclipse? If so, can I do it for other programs like Apache-Maven `mvn`-command?

I don't want to use "aliases" because I cannot setup and eclipse alias, when "eclipse" is listed in the apt repository. It seems as if only if I install the eclipse from `apt-get install` I can start eclipse from a single command in the terminal.

I appreciate any help, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use an *alias* for that. I think that there is an answer for this in other post. I'll search for it an let you know (you can also search around similar posts)

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/q/17536/62483) it is :)

Comment: but this doesnt work if the program is already listed in the apt repositories.

Comment: No because you won't need it. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: the thing is with aliases I cannot setup my manual install to use the ´eclipse´-command. Instead I can use something like ´eclipse1´, but I'd like to "overwrite" ´eclipse´(from the apt repository, which is NOT installed on my pc). It might seem a little silly, but I like to install things manually, and I just thought if I could use the standard commands instead of remembering a lot of standardcommand-derivatives?

Comment: Are you sure that the `alias` doesn't work? Have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

You may be totally wrong when you say: "I cannot setup an eclipse alias, when "eclipse" is listed in the apt repository". That's because the sequence adopted by the BASH shell to search for how to execute your command is as follow:

> 1. Before a command is executed REDIRECTION is done. Then following sequence used by SHELL
> 2. ALIASES
> 3. Parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable
> 4. Shell FUNCTION
> 5. BUILTIN command
> 6. HASH tables
> 7. PATH variable
> 8. If everything fails, you see command not found error message and if an appropriate packet exist in repositories, it will let you know.

<sup>Source: [How BASH Shell Command Search Sequence Works](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html).</sup>

So you can use all your aliases with confidence.

Anyway, here is a list of choices about how to "create a new terminal command" for `eclipse`:

- Create a new alias:

  ```bash
  alias eclipse="/path/to/eclipse"
  ```

  Se also: [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414/147044)
- Create a new shell function called `eclipse`:

  ```bash
  eclipse () { /path/to/eclipse; }
  ```

  Add this function at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file if you want to use it every time when you open the terminal.
- Create a new bash script called `eclipse`:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  /path/to/eclipse
  ```

  Save this script in your`~/bin` directory and don't forget to make it executable using the following command:

  ```bash
  chmod +x ~/bin/eclipse
  ```
- Create a symbolic link for `eclipse`:

  ```bash
  sudo ln -s /path/to/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
  ```
- Add `/path/to/eclipse` to your `PATH` environment variable ([this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/372234/147044)):

  ```bash
  PATH="/path/to/eclipse:$PATH"
  ```

  See also: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/147044)

Now, the choice is yours!

Answer (score 4):

You should add the directory where eclipse is to your path:

```
PATH=/path/to/eclipse/bin:$PATH
```

Editing your `.bashrc` file and adding that line at the end, should solve your issue. Restarting your terminal (ie. logging out, or opening another terminal) should allow you to verify your actions:

```
which eclipse
/path/to/eclipse/bin/eclipse
```