# Why doesn't the `time` command work with any option?

Tags: command-line, bash, time-command

I tried to use `time` command with `-f` option to format the output of time, but I get the following error:

```
-f: command not found
```

Then I tried to use other options `-a`, `-o`, etc and I get the same error. Not even `time --version` doesn't work (`--version: command not found`).

Don't tell me to read the man because I already do it by many times... All these options are specified there. So, where could be the problem?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall time` help?

Comment: Or maybe the internal shell `time` with `/usr/bin/time`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Well, even if you don't like it, I will put you to read again with more attention `man time`. At the end of `EXAMPLES` section you will find:

```
  Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
  the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.  On system
  where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become
       /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts
```

So, I'm assuming that you use bash shell which uses an internal version of `time`, provided as a shell keyword. You can check this using the following command:

```
type time
```

and the output will probably be:

```
time is a shell keyword
```

If this is the case, then it is clear that to use **the real** `time` command you must use its explicit path: `/usr/bin/time`.

Further, if you don't want to use anymore the shell keyword `time`, you can [create a permanent alias](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414/147044) as follow:

```
alias time='/usr/bin/time'
```

This will overwrite the shell keyword `time` because the command:

```
type time
```

will give the following output now:

```
time is aliased to `/usr/bin/time'
```

Comment: for the shell built commands: {info time} and {type time}. For the binary commands: {which time} and {man time}

Comment: @Michael `info time` is about the binary. `help time` is about the builtin.

Comment: yep, sorry I was thinking "help" but out came "info"

Comment: I skimmed the `man` page three times and still missed the `bash` caveat.  I guess the adage is RTFM and not SkimTFM for a reason...

Comment: Rather than write out the full path to the binary, you can escape a command (i.e. `\time`) to avoid it being interpreted as a shell builtin or alias.

Answer (score 28):

Since, as the other answers explain, `time` is a shell keyword, the only option available to you is `-p`:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ help time
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.

Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.

Options:
  -p    print the timing summary in the portable Posix format
```

So, you need to run the `time` that's in `/usr/bin`. Here are a few ways to do so:

- Use the `time` executable instead:

  ```
  /usr/bin/time -f %Uuser ls >/dev/null
  ```
- Use `\` which causes your shell to ignore aliases and keywords and instead search your `$PATH` for a matching executable:

  ```
  \time -f %Uuser ls >/dev/null
  ```
- Use the `command` builtin which has a similar effect:

  ```
  command time -f %Uuser ls >/dev/null
  ```
- Use a different shell, one that has no such keyword. For example `sh` (which is actually `dash` on Ubuntu):

  ```
  sh -c "time -f %Uuser ls >/dev/null"
  ```
- Use `which`,  which will search through your `$PATH` (OK, this one is silly):

  ```
  $(which time) -f %Uuser ls >/dev/null
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite - replicate built-in `time` with regular `/usr/bin/time`? I.e. to translate bash script into dash.

Comment: @DanM. I don't understand. If you want the builtin `time`, run `time`. If you want the standalone executable, run `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: there is no built-in `time` on Ubuntu's default shell as far as I'm aware. I want to translate script using built-in into standalone with the same behavior.

Comment: @DanM. then just use `time`. It will call whichever one is available. That will be the builtin for bash and the standalone for dash. If you use `/usr/bin/time`, then it will always call the standalone, both in bash and in dash. But it sounds like you should probably be asking a new question, explaining the behavior you need. Let me know if you do and I'll try and help.

Comment: yeah, but built-in and standalone have drastically different syntax/semantics. Anyway, thanks. I'll ask a new question if I won't figure out how to deal with it myself.

Comment: @DanM. if you write your script so it always uses `/usr/bin/time`, then you don't need to worry about if it is being run by `dash` or `bash`.

Answer (score 17):

The `bash` and `zsh` shells have their internal `time` command. You have to use

```
/usr/bin/time -f ...
```

BTW, I discovered that using (from `zsh`):

```
~% which  time
time: shell reserved word
```