# Why doesn’t Ubuntu's `time` follow the standard POSIX format and how do I change it?

Tags: command-line, posix-compliant

If you measure times in Ubuntu 18.04, the result apears in a single line:

```
$ time sleep 1
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.003 total
```

This doesn’t align with the POSIX standard, as described in `time`’s man page:

```
-p, --portability
       Use the following format string, for conformance with POSIX standard 1003.2:
                 real %e
                 user %U
                 sys %S
```

Now my question is:

Why does Ubuntu use its own format for displaying resource usage?

Also, how do I change the behavior? Using the `-p` option from the manual I cited above, I only get the following error:

```
$ time -p sleep 1           
zsh: command not found: -p
-p sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 73% cpu 0.002 total
```

Comment: @guiverc Please post that as an answer, thanks! (To be clear, the comments section is not suitable for answers.)

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the `time` command work with any option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434289/why-doesnt-the-time-command-work-with-any-option)

Comment: Why the downvote? What should I improve about this question? It wasn't obvious to me that `time`was a `zsh` built-in in my case that doesn't align with the man page of the installed standalone binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is a huge clue -

> zsh: command not found: -p

You are using zsh not BASH or DASH.

> The man page for time pertains to the external /usr/bin/time program:
> bash as well as zsh provides its own time shell builtin (which happens
> to have an equivalent -p switch)
>
> *correcting comment by @steeldriver*

I get a different result on my standard Ubuntu using the default bash - or what you no doubt want/expect.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$  time -p sleep 1
real 1.09
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

Comment: The man page for `time` pertains to the external `/usr/bin/time` program: `bash` as well as `zsh` provides its own `time` shell builtin (which happens to have an equivalent `-p` switch), but it's not really correct to say that the man pages are "for bash/dash/sh"

Comment: … so the answer is: To use the external `time` rather than any shell builtin, call it with its full path `/usr/bin/time -p sleep 1`!

Comment: `zsh`, right! I could've realized that on my own, but thank you for clarifying this.