# Combine 2 commands into 1 Custom command?

Tags: command-line

I want a custom command named something like "ServerStart" or something which is a combination of two commands, one after the other.

- The first command would be `cd .Server`
- The second being `java -Xmx7168M -Xms7168M -jar server.jar`

How do I do this so this becomes one Terminal command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `alias` is used to make a short custom command for one or more long commands. See [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)

You can combine two command as,

```
command1 && command2
```

Then `command2` will be issued if `command1` is successfully executed. So make an alias like,

```
alias ServerStart='cd /path/to/.Server && java -Xmx7168M -Xms7168M -jar server.jar'
```

Source `~/.bashrc` as `. ~/.bashrc`. After that the command `ServerStart` will issue both the commands together for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **alias** command .

For more help visit this site [Site](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ualias.htm) .

Open terminal :

```
alias ServerStart=' cd /path/to/.Server ; java -Xmx7168M -Xms7168M -jar server.jar '
```

So now when you type **ServerStart** in terminal it will execute the two commands .

To save , so you can use it all the time add the following in you `~/.bashrc` file .

```
ServerStar() {
   cd .Server
    java -Xmx7168M -Xms7168M -jar server.jar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the first command be `cd .Server` you can have the command be `java -Xmx7168M -Xms7168M -jar /full path here/server.jar`

Put it in a text file and save it at `/usr/bin/ServerStart`. `chmod +x /usr/bin/ServerStart`

Comment: Instead of `/usr/bin/`, you can create a folder named `bin` (or whatever) in your home folder, then add it your `PATH` by appending the line `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bashrc` file.