# How to excute several commands with one command

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

Usually I need to exceute several commands every time Im at work, start local server, start docker bash, run frontend service...and I wish I could do all those stuff with one single command.

I tried using an alias, but the implementation I saw were more in the field of making long commands shorter, but I wasn't able to make an alias with several commands.

Any idea if is possible to run a series of commands one after the other with one single command?

Comment: It seems it should actually be pointed to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334941/how-to-combine-multiple-commands-in-terminal) instead, as the one pointed to is also a duplicate.

Comment: @ArturMeinild yes, but the current dupe has some examples (https://askubuntu.com/a/497869/158442, https://askubuntu.com/a/497868/158442) which are more directly applicable to OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain several commands directly on the command line.

One option is to use a semicolon, like this:

```
command1; command2; command3
```

This will fire all 3 commands after each other, unconditionally.

You can also use a logical operator, like this:

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

`&&` is an "and" operator, and in this case `command2` will only execute if `command1` is successful etc.

You can also use this construction in aliases (with no need for a script), like this:

```
alias mycommand='command1; command2; command3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Running several commands is pretty simple thanks to a script. Create any text file you want (e.g. a hidden file into your home).

```
gedit ~/.myscript.sh
```

Put the following content

```
#!/bin/bash

<my command 1>
<my command 2>
...
```

Make the file executable.

```
chmod +x ~/.myscript.sh
```

Then you can run the script with the following command.

```
~/.myscript.sh
```

Finally, you can add an alias into your `~/.bashrc`.

```
alias mycommand=~/.myscript.sh
```

So you can use `mycommand` to execute your script.