# sqlplus: command not found on Ubuntu

Tags: oracle

I just installed Oracle Database 11g R2 on Ubuntu.

I tried to run `sqlplus` but I got this message :

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

These are the values of : $ORACLE_SID, $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH

```
aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $ORACLE_SID

aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/
aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

How can I solve this problem ?

## Edit :

I tried to enter to the `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin` and run the `./sqlplus` command instead of sqlplus and it worked, but I want to execute `sqlplus` without entering to that path everytime.

Comment: How did you install the package? Via apt? A .deb?

Comment: @musher I installed the .deb which I downloaded from Oracle's website

Comment: Try this and report back the results: `sudo find /usr /bin /sbin /root -name sqlplus`

Comment: @musher it returns nothing :/, please see the edit I made to my question

Comment: The installation should have placed a small shell script named `oraenv` in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. If you type `. oraenv`, does it make your shell's PATH include the `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin` directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution for you I believe is to add a soft link in `/bin` to the actual location of the binary.

`ln -s /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin/sqlplus /bin/sqlplus`

This will allow all users to call sqlplus from wherever.

Comment: your example command is referencing a different directory than the one you mentioned prior.

Comment: Good point, fixed that. Strictly speaking it would've worked eitherway since `/usr/bin` is on his PATH

Comment: Yes, and if we wanted to stick to tradition, we'd create the link into `/usr/bin`, but it doesn't really matter from a practical perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options here, but I will list what I believe to be the easiest/simplest.

Note: each of these is an independent solution. These do not compose a series of steps.

1. Locate the actual sqlplus binary and add that directory to your path. This relatively-ancient post is still extremely relevent for this task:
   [askubuntu - how to add a directory to my path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)
2. Locate the binary and create a soft link to the bin directory in your user's home directory. Here is the command for that:

   ```
   ln -s /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin/sqlplus $HOME/bin/sqlplus
   ```

   Alternatively for all users to have this functionality:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus
   ```
3. Create an alias that calls the binary via its full path through environment variables. This tutorial gives you instructions for how to do that: [askubuntu - How to create a permanent alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)
   The line for your alias would look like this:

   ```
   alias sqlplus='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin/sqlplus'
   ```
4. Call the command directly by specifying the entire path every time:

   ```
   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin/sqlplus
   ```

Comment: when I tried the first command I got this message :

ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/aimad/bin/sqlplus’: No such file or directory

Comment: I do not see a message. If it was complaining that "file or directory does not exist", create your directory first with `mkdir $HOME/bin`