# Location of "~/.bash_aliases"

Tags: 14.10, bashrc, alias

I want to make permanent aliases in Terminal, and I have read this answer on how to do it: https://askubuntu.com/a/5278/364819

But I have got a small problem, I have found the code:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

As refereed to in the answer. But I cannot actually find the `.bash_aliases` file which I can set these permanent aliases in.

So my question is, where is the location of this file, and if I need to create it, do I just create it in my home user directory directory?

I am running on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: If it's not there in your home directory, feel free to create the file. That's why the code snipped first tests for file existence before trying to source it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`~/.bash_aliases` is a full path already. The tilde (`~`) is expanded by the shell (and many other applications) to your full home path (aka `$HOME`, usually `/home/$USER`).

It doesn't exist by default, so just create one.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, just create it in your home directory.

`touch ~/.bash_aliases`  or open an empty file in a text editor, e.g.,

`gedit ~/.bash_aliases`

This should be one of your first aliases..

```
##### ea - alias for editing aliases
#
#When setting up a new aliases file, or having creating a new file.. About every time after editing an aliases file, I source it. This alias makes editing alias a
#bit easier and they are useful right away. Note if the source failed, it will not echo "aliases sourced".
#
#Sub in gedit for your favorite editor, or alter for ksh, sh, etc.
#
alias ea='gedit ~/.bash_aliases; source ~/.bash_aliases && source $HOME/.bash_aliases && echo "aliases sourced  --ok."'
#
```

When you run across something that would be a good alias, enter `ea`, a text editor opens.  Add your new alias.  Close the editor.  The alias automagically sources; makes the new alias immediately available; and you're on your way.