# Problem while trying to create an alias

Tags: command-line, bash, matlab, alias

Goodmorning

I was trying to create an alias so as to launch matlab easier.

I read this post :[How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) and I used the commands in this line

```
echo "alias "/home/user/matlab/bin/matlab='matlab'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then every time I tried to launch matlab I get the error  get the error "Segmentation violation detected".

Plus, in the terminal I have the message

```
"bash: alias: « /home/vangel/matlab/bin/matlab » : nom d'alias non valable".
```

Could you help me find out what's happening?
(I'm new to linux and I hope I described well my problem)

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to make an alias. Easily just add the `matlab bin` directory to your PATH.

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/matlab/bin
```

add this line also to `.bashrc` and then `source .bashrc` if you want to make it permanent. NOw you can run the command `matlab` with no need to create an alias.

But to know your error above, you probably have understand syntax of alias in wrong way.

The command syntax is

```
alias alias-name="command"
```

example

```
alias l='ls -CF'
```

So in your case you have to write alias in this way

```
alias matlab='/home/user/matlab/bin/matlab'
```

So correct the writing and either insert it to `.bash_aliases` or add it directly to `.bashrc` and then run comman `source .bashrc` or `source .bash_aliases`

Another way of thinking.