Dell precision 5680 webcam working in 24.04/ Using HAL library for MIPI camera
Hi I am having a difficult time finding out how to get my dell webcam working. I need to do some meetings and its a huge headache.
I have seen this thread, however it is for 22.04....
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414...n-ubuntu-22-04
Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks I appreciate it.

I don't have a solution. It appears to me that Canonical is going to have to put out something new for 24.04. I believe this is the relevant documentation for prior versions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelMIPICamera
